# Issue in passing array from xcode to javascript using SBJason

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview

I am trying to pass an array from xcode to my local html.Basically I am using Jquery in html, so to read HTML as well as included .js files m using `loadHTMLstring:` with `baseURL`. Now I'm facing a problem in using `stringByevaluatingjavascriptfromstring` to load webview. The code is :

```
NSString *java=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"javafunction('%@');",json];
[webView loadHTMLString:content baseURL:baseURL];    
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:java];
```

in my HTML I'm using:

```
function javafunction(inp) {
  var arr=newArray(); 
  arr='inp'; 
  alert(arr[0]);
}
```

Comment: Is `var arr=newArray();` what appears in your code or do you have a space as in `var arr = new /* NOT SPACE HERE */ Array();`

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
var arr=newArray(); 
arr='inp';
```

should be

```
var arr = new Array(); 
arr[0] = inp;
```

which sets the zero-th element of the array to the string `'inp'` or

```
var arr = [inp];
```

which uses the abbreviated array syntax
or even

```
var arr = new Array();
arr.push('inp');
```

which uses `Array`'s `push` method to add the input parameter, `inp`, to the end of the array.

`newArray` will probably just result in an error like `newArray is not defined`, and `arr='inp'` would replace the array with a string instead of putting the string into the array.

EDIT:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"javafunction('%@');",json]
```

is probably not what you want.   If `json` is a JSON-encoded string then you probably want to remove the single-quotes.  If it is not a JSON-encoded string, then you probably want to JSON-encode it.

This may be a minor issue, but you should also be aware that not all JSON strings are valid JavaScript expressions because JSON allows unicode codepoints U+2028 and U+2029 in strings but that codepoint is a newline in JavaScript.  I.e. the JavaScript expression `eval(JSON.stringify("\u2028"))` fails with an exception.

Comment: I think that 'inp' is not assumed as a string, but as a variable so, maybe the correct form should be `arr[0] = inp;`.

Comment: @Sylter, quite possibly.  Rehan, was that your intent?

Comment: @Mike Samuel I understood what r u trying to say on javascript side.But i wanna know that whether the array 'json' is been passed from xcode since m loading webview for the second time

Comment: @rehan, Please see my edit.  Also, the variable name `java` is confusing when used as an abbreviation of `javascript`.